# How can I create a plot that overlays point data with an unequally spaced matrix plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to create a plot similar to the attached image where point data is laid over a matrix color plot:

[image: Excel plot overlaying point chart over coloured cells]

I have `x` and `y` data. I have then created matrix `xy_bincount` by counting the number of points in `x` and `y` that lie within my xy bin combinations. The bin width are not uniform as can be seen in the attached fig.

Would it be easier to create this plot in R, Matlab or Python?

Thanks for the help!

```
x<-c(2.56481, 2.11009, 1.72927, 1.47803, 1.74279, 3.29555, 3.66061, 2.63349, 2.43808, 2.13, 3.09267, 2.3555, 2.48811, 4.05344, 3.38401, 2.69907, 2.26378, 2.71978)
y<-c(-1.26044, 13.6098, 0.710325, -4.27657, 11.1908, -7.2431, -3.19167, 20.7423, 10.009, 32.12, 42.6192, 13.9598, -0.412724, -20.3846, -6.97259, -14.2046, 8.30859, 0.0386572)
xylabels<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R")

xy_bincount<-matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 6, 12, 0, 0, 24, 6, 0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, 12, 6),nrow = 5, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: There are negative values in `y` vector, at which position in `xy_bincount` matrix do they have to go (given matrix doesn't have dim names)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
y_breaks <-  c(-25,-15,-5,5,15, 55)
x_breaks <-  c(0,0.5,1.5,3, 4.5)
foo <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
tibble(x,y) %>% 
  mutate(y_bins=cut(y, breaks = y_breaks, labels = y_breaks[-1],include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  mutate(x_bins=cut(x, breaks = x_breaks , labels = x_breaks[-1], include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  add_count(y_bins, x_bins) %>% 
  mutate(percent=n/n()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(data = . %>% 
                     select(y_bins , x_bins, percent) %>% 
                     complete(y_bins, x_bins, fill=list(percent=0)) %>% 
                     distinct(), 
              aes(x=foo(x_bins)-0.15, y=foo(y_bins)-2, label=scales::percent(percent)),
              color="red")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_breaks, limits = c(0,4.5), expand = c(0, 0), minor_breaks=NULL,position="top") +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = y_breaks, limits = c(55,-25), expand = c(0, 0),minor_breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

for the rectangles you can use this hardcoded solution.

```
# calculate the positions for the rectangle, e.g. xmin, ymin and xmax, ymax
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  select(y_bins , x_bins, percent) %>% 
  complete(y_bins, x_bins, fill=list(percent=0)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  bind_cols(
    tibble(y_start=y_breaks[-6],
           y_end=y_breaks[-1]) %>% 
      bind_rows(.,.,.,.) %>% 
      arrange(y_start)    %>%  
      mutate(x_start=rep(x_breaks[-5],5),
             x_end=rep(x_breaks[-1],5))) %>% 
  mutate(percent_gr=as.numeric(gsub("%","",percent)))
# and the plot
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_rect(data = df2,
            aes(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end, ymin=y_start, ymax=y_end, fill=percent_gr),
            alpha=0.8,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(data = . %>% 
              select(y_bins , x_bins, percent) %>% 
              complete(y_bins, x_bins, fill=list(percent=0)) %>% 
              distinct(), 
              aes(x=foo(x_bins)-0.15, y=foo(y_bins)-2, label=percent))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_breaks, limits = c(0,4.5), expand = c(0, 0), minor_breaks=NULL,position="top") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = y_breaks, limits = c(55,-25), expand = c(0, 0), minor_breaks=NULL) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
   theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

And finally you can try the all in one solution using geom_tile

```
tibble(x,y) %>% 
  mutate(y_bins=cut(y, breaks = y_breaks, labels = y_breaks[-1],include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  mutate(x_bins=cut(x, breaks = x_breaks , labels = x_breaks[-1], include.lowest = T)) %>% 
  add_count(y_bins, x_bins) %>% 
  mutate(percent=scales::percent(n/n())) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
    geom_tile(data = . %>% 
                select(y_bins , x_bins, percent) %>% 
                complete(y_bins, x_bins, fill=list(percent=0)) %>% 
                distinct() %>% 
                group_by(y_bins) %>% 
                mutate(w=-(lag(foo(x_bins),default = 0)-foo(x_bins)),
                       x=foo(x_bins)-w/2) %>% 
                group_by(x_bins) %>% 
                arrange(x_bins) %>% 
                mutate(h=-(lag(foo(y_bins),default = -25)-foo(y_bins)),
                       y=foo(y_bins)-h/2) %>% 
                mutate(percent_gr=as.numeric(gsub("%","",percent))),
              aes(y=y, x=x,width=w,height=h, fill=percent_gr))+
    geom_point() + 
  geom_text(data = . %>% 
              select(y_bins , x_bins, percent) %>% 
              complete(y_bins, x_bins, fill=list(percent=0)) %>% 
              distinct(), 
            aes(x=foo(x_bins)-0.15, y=foo(y_bins)-2, label=percent))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_breaks, limits = c(0,4.5), expand = c(0, 0), minor_breaks=NULL,position="top") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = y_breaks, limits = c(55,-25), expand = c(0, 0),minor_breaks=NULL) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  theme_linedraw()
```

Comment: You can also use `-Inf` and `Inf` in the breaks vectors to account for really large or small values. However, the question isn't clear on the bins as the axes show different to the annotations

Comment: Thanks @Jimbou! This is exactly what I needed. I am able to tweak your code to use with other data I have. Any advice on how I can place my labels outside the x and y axis?

Comment: @Cicatrixx by now I have no solution for this, try to play with `theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(1, "cm"))`. But I recommend to use inkscape or photshop for this.